# Proper maps and their codomains

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

A continuous map $f:X\to Y$ is called proper map if for every compact $K\subset\subset Y$ the set $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact.

Now, if $\mathbb D=\{z\in \mathbb C;|z|<1\}$. Why the map $f:\mathbb D\to \mathbb D$ given by $f(z)=z^2$ is proper while  $g:\mathbb D\to \mathbb C$ given by $g(z)=z^2$ is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $f$ is proper as any compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$ is closed (in the topology of $\mathbb{C}$ and not in the subspace topology), and preimages of closed sets are closed, and closed subsets are closed, as the map $z \mapsto z^2$ on $\mathbb{C}$ restricts to $\mathbb{D}$.

For $g$ take the closed compact ball $B_2(0)$ of radius 2. The preimage of this ball under $g$ is $\mathbb{D}$ which is not compact.